# event not being called on socket.on('connect', event)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm having an issue with socket.io, at least I think, where a function in my client code is not being called on `socket.on('connect', onsocketConnected);`

However, if I put a conditional such as:

```
if(socket.connect) {
    onsocketConnected();
}
```

Then my function gets called. Also I just realized if I write it like
`socket.on('connect', onsocketConnected());` that my function gets called correctly. My question is, upon a connection from the client to a server, is connect a value that is automatically supplied to the client? Looking at the documentation at https://socket.io/docs/client-api/ it states it should work as `socket.on(event, callback function)`.
Are the parenthesis in the callback function always required for it to work? Because it seems like they are working elsewhere without parenthesis. Any resources or pointers to documentation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a function (callback or whatever), while the function does not get any arguments, you should still call it with `()` . I.E: `onsocketConnected`***`()`***`;`

The reason `socket.on('connect', onsocketConnected);` didn't work is because you are missing `()` while calling for a function. 

What you are doing by this, is just passing the **variable/object** (which does not exist) `onsocketConnected` to `socket.on` method, instead of passing a **Function.**

The right way to use it, is just as you typed afterwards: `socket.on('connect', onsocketConnected());`

Documentation about JS function arguments: http://devdocs.io/javascript/functions/arguments

Comment: I'm really new to JS, thanks for the link to some documentation and an explanation.

Comment: socket.on('connect', onsocketConnected()); I'm totally agree with this.